# TSQL: combine date ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
date       |   rate
2014-01-01 |  100
2014-01-02 |  100
2014-01-03 |  1
2014-01-04 |  1
2014-01-05 |  100
2014-01-06 |  100
2014-01-07 |  1
2014-01-08 |  1
2014-01-09 |  100
2014-01-10 |  100
2014-01-11 |  100
2014-01-12 |  100
```

I'd like to get the following

```
date start      |   date end  | rate
2014-01-01      |  2014-01-02 |  100
2014-01-03      |  2014-01-04 |  1
2014-01-05      |  2014-01-06 |  100
2014-01-07      |  2014-01-08 |  1
2014-01-09      |  2014-01-12 |  100
```

And so on. Of course, numbers could be different.

How can I do that in TSQL? I use SQL Server 2012 just in case.

Comment: Is the date column continuous?

Comment: Yes, it contains rates for several years. And it's one day-one rate.

Comment: the last example isn't continuous i.e. all previous increment by 2 days each and the last increments by 4. Are the ranges something you will pre-define (and may be different) or will you always expect them to follow a pattern?

Comment: I cant post the answer, something went wrong on the SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem named "gap and island problem". I cant post answer here so I have created the fiddle:

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0b00e/3)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select [date] d,rate, case when lead(rate, 1, 0) over (order by [date])  = rate then 1    else 0 end ld
 from tbl),

filtered as
(select *, rank() over (partition by ld order by d) rn
 from cte)

select f.d [date start], s.d [date end], f.rate
from filtered f
inner join filtered s on f.rn = s.rn
and f.ld = 1 and s.ld = 0
```

Hamlet's answer is of course, correct. I wanted to present an alternative solution. We use the `LEAD` analytic function to identify the start of a new range of values, and then use `RANK` to get the rows corresponding to the required start and end dates of each range.

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/QXVNKQ47535).

**UPDATE**: `LEAD` is available from SQL Server 2012 onwards, so while it will work in OP's case, it will not work for older versions.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Thanks for pointing out the error in my previous query. I have updated it now.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `LEAD` is only supported from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Comment: @adaskos Fair enough. Although since OP mentioned he was using SQL Server 2012, I didn't think of making it explicit in my answer when I wrote it.